# Game textures created entirely using OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

Would it be possible to create textures like these, i.e. in a programmatic manner?

[image: these]

I have tried to search games for which the textures have been created entirely using OpenGL, but without luck. Do you know any examples of such games?

Comment: I'm very sure that this textures have been painted by an artist.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Me too, but that does not change the hypothetical question about whether or not it _could_ have been created using OpenGL.

Comment: @sostack Of course it can be created, but that will be a hard work and probably to broad for a stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's perfectly possible. Google for "procedural generation". Here's a game that does everything procedurally (graphics, audio, and so on) albeit not using OpenGL but DirectX: http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=12036 the source code of the engine and tooling for this game can be found at https://github.com/farbrausch/fr_public/tree/master/werkkzeug3_kkrieger

Comment: It was something like that I was looking for, thanks man! But wow, so the game does not use any handmade textures? That would be quite unbelievable.

Comment: @sostack: I think what's more impressive is the size of the final product. The whole game, a full blown FPS, including music, sound effects, graphics assets, levels and engine is fully contained in a single executable of exactly a mere 96kB (kilobytes).